Text and label colors in math formulas in LyX
I just upgraded my LyX 2.3.7 to LyX 2.4.1 and my LyX is running on macOS Sonoma 14.6.1.
I have a color-related issue for math (both inline and displays), displayed on my LyX screen.
By default, the content of a math display is colored blue. Now, however, the equation label, texts, and also some math functions (such as \sup, \lim, etc.) inside a math display are colored in black as in this picture:

The same happens with inline math. In this math display, I typed:
default\ math\ \text{text is black}\mathrm{mathrm}\sup
I think this is not supposed to be. The picture in https://wiki.lyx.org/LyX/NewInLyX24#display has equation labels in blue (the same color as the usual parts of math) and this is what I want to get. Currently, all these black-colored parts in math seem to be considered as "text" in LyX >> Preferences >> Look & Feel >> Colors. If I change this "text" color, then the whole body text changes to that color, which is not what I wanted.
How can I have all these parts in math also colored in blue? It worked fine with my previous version LyX 2.3.7, before I upgraded to LyX 2.4.1.
